# The point where I got stuck about using autoDispose in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, riverpod, autodispose

I would like to discuss about a code.
I am using **autoDispose** in my application but there is a point that confuses me.
I am using this **autoDispose** with **ConsumerWidget** and I am not sure if it is disposed properly.
I am sharing the code below, could you please take a look at it if you have a chance to review the code?
Note: I prefer to use ConsumerWidget for efficient performance and I thought I could use autoDispose in this way since I am using riverpod.
I used static for security reasons but I am not sure if it causes any issues.

Also, I used **ref.onDispose()** inside autoDispose, maybe this code is excessive and I already disposed it manually...
Thank you in advance for your help...

I am using this autoDispose with ConsumerWidget and I want to make sure that it is properly disposed when **dispose()** is called.

```
class ControlTextField extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ControlTextField({super.key});

  static final _textController = Provider.autoDispose<TextEditingController>(
    (ref) {
      final controller = TextEditingController();

      ref.onDispose(() {
        controller.dispose();
      });

      return controller;
    },
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final FocusNode firstFocusNode = FocusNode();
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        const Icon(Icons.receipt, size: 16),
        const SizedBox(width: 8),
        Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Text('Work List',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium)),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            child: Consumer(
              builder: (context, watch, _) {
                final textEditingController = ref.watch(_textController);

                return TextField(
                  controller: textEditingController,
                  onChanged: (event) {
                    final textEditingController = ref.read(_textController);

                    debugPrint(textEditingController.value.text);
                  },
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  onTapOutside: (b) {
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                  },
                  focusNode: firstFocusNode,
                  enableSuggestions: true,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Ara...',
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 12),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  autofocus: false,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly for these purposes, you can use a couple of packages:

- [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks)
- [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod)

And your code will look like this:

```dart
class ControlTextField extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const ControlTextField({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final firstFocusNode = useFocusNode();
    final textEditingController = useTextEditingController();
    
    // .. lots of other code
    return TextField(
      controller: textEditingController,
      onChanged: (event) {
        // do something
        
        debugPrint(textEditingController.text);
      },
      onTapOutside: (_) {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
      focusNode: firstFocusNode,
    );
  }
}
```

In this case, we are using the `HookConsumerWidget` class, which allows the use of hooks in the `build` method. Hooks are things that will be disposed of on their own if necessary. Also, you can add some parameters to `useTextEditingController.fromValue(...)`, such as initial text.

I also changed your `FocusNode` object, which also needs to be properly disposed of.

---

If you don't like hooks for whatever reason, use the `ConsumerStatefulWidget` widget and the `initState()` and `dispose()` methods to define any of your controllers and dispose of them afterwards. This way you better show your intentions in the code.

Comment: But what I'm wondering is whether the code below will automatically dispose of the TextEditingController: static final _textController = Provider.autoDispose<TextEditingController>((ref) => TextEditingController());"

Comment: Yes, it will. And you can check this by adding this line to the provider itself: `ref.onDispose(() { print('has been disposed'); });`